# typeorm-model-generator issue for Oracle DB

Tags: node.js, oracle, typeorm

I am facing the below error while using typeorm-model-generator for Oracle DB.

```
Error connecting to Oracle Server.
Error occurred in typeorm-model-generator.
typeorm-model-generator@0.4.0  node@v12.6.0
If you think this is a bug please open an issue including this log on https://github.com/Kononnable/typeorm-model-generator/issues
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
(node:12680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor
(node:12680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
 block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12680) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate th
e Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Used "npx typeorm-model-generator" command with interactive options.
Auto-generated .tomg-config file detail:

```
{
    "host": "hostIP",
    "port": 1521,
    "databaseName": "TestUser",
    "user": "TestUser",
    "password": "*******",
    "databaseType": "oracle",
    "schemaName": "",
    "ssl": false,
    "skipTables": []
  }
```

Has anyone tried typeorm model generator with oracle db ? Please help ?

Comment: Is `databaseName` correct?  To me it sounds like it will be the service name of the DB used in the connection string but you have it set to the same as the db user name.

Comment: Thanks .!! worked by changing databaseName to sid.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add connect string to get it working:

```
    {
   "type": "oracle",
   "host": "localhost",
   "username": "orm",
   "password": "orm",
   "connectString": "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = localhost)(Port = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = ORCLPDB1)(SERVER=dedicated)))",
   "synchronize": true,
   "privilege": 2,
   "logging": false,
   "entities": [
      "src/entity/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "migrations": [
      "src/migration/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "subscribers": [
      "src/subscriber/**/*.ts"
   ],
   "cli": {
      "entitiesDir": "src/entity",
      "migrationsDir": "src/migration",
      "subscribersDir": "src/subscriber"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer for anyone coming across this problem, it is very likely that the **"databaseName"** field is wrong.

Putting **"ORCL"** into this field worked for me.